# Why is `noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement` automatically added to the activity created through the wizard

Tags: android

My activity created through a wizard hash the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
```

What is this piece of code here?

```
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without `//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement`, the editor warns you because this could be simplified to:

```
return id == R.id.action_settings;
```

But that's probably not what you want here, you will need to put something in the `if` later (e.g. launch a Settings activity).

Comment: thanks, but why is this code added there by default? I don't mean comment disabling inspection, I mean `return id == R.id.action_settings;`

Comment: Do you understand how [`onOptionsItemSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) works? The wizard creates a *Settings* menu by default, so this code means: "if the *Settings* menu is clicked, do something" (here it just returns `true`).

Comment: The template really should have a comment in the if block to "Add Settings handling here".  Not sure if that resolves the over-eager editor warning.